# Como hago para pedir los datos separados " " y agregarlos en un vector

Tags: java, array, netbeans, bucle-for, bucles

Buenos noches tengo un problema y es como hago para pedir los datos separados " " y agregarlos en un vector, intente esto

```
    ArrayList<Receta> recetario = new ArrayList<>();
    public int n;
    System.out.println("Cantos ingredientes va a agregar");
    n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    String [] ingredientesApoyo = new String [n];
    System.out.println("Ingrese los ingredientes separados por (&)");
    String [] texto2 = sc.nextLine().split("&");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ingredientesApoyo[i] = texto2[i];
    }
```

n es el tamaño del vector

```
   class Receta {[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
   private String ingredientes[] = new String[n];
   public void setIngredientes(String[] ingredientes) {
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
     }
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi tienes todo listo, para la asignación sería así:

```
ingredientesApoyo[i] = texto2[i];
```

Y  el arreglo `ingredientesApoyo` debe crearse después de pedir el valor de `n`.

El código quedaría así:

```
public int n;
System.out.println("Cantos ingredientes va a agregar");
n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
String [] ingredientesApoyo = new String [n];
System.out.println("Ingrese los ingredientes separados por (&)");
String [] texto2 = sc.nextLine().split("&");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ingredientesApoyo[i] = texto2[i];
}
```

Para pasarlo por un método:
Receta receta = new Receta();
receta.setIngredientes(ingredientesApoyo);

Y en la clase `Receta` no hace falta inicializar el arreglo `ingredientes`:

```
class Receta {
   private String ingredientes[];
   public void setIngredientes(String[] ingredientes) {
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
     }
  }
```

Comment: bro otra pregunta quiero pasar ingredienteApoyo a un metodo set como hago mira en la pregunta, y en el set pasarlos al vector ingredientes

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: oye una pregunta en que linea lo agrego porque me da error

Comment: Abajo  del `for` solo que primero  hay que crear un objeto `Receta` . ` Receta receta = new Receta();`

Comment: mira la en la pregunta me sale nullPoint

Comment: las variables `recetario` y `receta` ya fueron inicializadas?

Comment: recetario es una array y si ya la inicialize

Comment: y `receta`? porque se crea una variable `recetaNew` me parece que esa es la que se desea usar.

Comment: para dar los datos en el constructor public                                        
 Receta(String nombre, int tiempoDePreparacion, String tipo, boolean estado) {  //talvez añadir el boolean estado preguntar
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tiempoDePreparacion = tiempoDePreparacion;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

Comment: No entendí eso último. No me has respondido si `receta` está inicializada

Comment: receta la tengo asi: private Receta receta;